# How to convert a Python string into its escaped version in C++?

Tags: python, c++, escaping

I'm trying to write a Python program that reads in a file and prints the contents as a single string as it would be escaped in a C++ format. This is because the string will be copied from Python output and pasted into a C++ program (C++ string variable definition).

Basically, I want to convert

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.card{
    max-width: 400px;
     min-height: 250px;
     background: #02b875;
     padding: 30px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: #FFF;
     margin:20px;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="card">
  <h4>The ESP32 Update web page without refresh</h4><br>
  <h1>Sensor Value:<span id="ADCValue">0</span></h1><br>
</div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with 0.1 Second interval
  getData();
}, 100); //100mSeconds update rate

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ADCValue").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readADC", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</html>
```

to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<style>\n.card{\n    max-width: 400px;\n     min-height: 250px;\n     background: #02b875;\n     padding: 30px;\n     box-sizing: border-box;\n     color: #FFF;\n     margin:20px;\n     box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);\n}\n</style>\n\n<body>\n<div class=\"card\">\n  <h4>The ESP32 Update web page without refresh</h4><br>\n  <h1>Sensor Value:<span id=\"ADCValue\">0</span></h1><br>\n</div>\n</body>\n\n<script>\nsetInterval(function() {\n  // Call a function repetatively with 0.1 Second interval\n  getData();\n}, 100); //100mSeconds update rate\n\nfunction getData() {\n  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();\n  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {\n    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n      document.getElementById(\"ADCValue\").innerHTML =\n      this.responseText;\n    }\n  };\n  xhttp.open(\"GET\", \"readADC\", true);\n  xhttp.send();\n}\n</script>\n</html>
```

Using this Python program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(<filepath>) as html:
        contents = html.read().replace('"', r'\"')

    print(contents)
    print('')
    print(repr(contents))
```

I get exactly what I want minus double backslashes when "escaping" the double quotes. I've tried a few random things, but all the attempts either get rid of both backslashes or don't change the string at all.

I simply want to add a single backslash before all the double quotes in my string. Is this even possible in Python?

Comment: Would be a lot easier with C++11's raw string literals. In fact the whole problem disappears. :)

Comment: You need to first replace all \ with \\, and only ***then*** replace " with \". If you think about it, for a minute, you will understand why.

Comment: What do you mean "minus double backslashes"? Are you saying you also want to escape the backslash? And the newlines?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I have my doubts about your method, can you provide a quick example?

Comment: @tdelaney - No, I do not want to escape the backslash. In fact, that's exactly what I'm trying to undo within the string. I simply need to find a way to insert one and only one backslash in front of each double quote in my string

Comment: What exactly kind of "doubts" do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.translate` to map the troublesome characters to their escaped equivalents. Since python's rules on escape and quote characters can be a bit baroque, I've just brute forced them for consistency.

```
# escapes for C literal strings
_c_str_trans = str.maketrans({"\n": "\\n", "\"":"\\\"", "\\":"\\\\"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(<filepath>) as html:
        contents = html.read().translate(_c_str_trans)

    print(contents)
    print('')
    print(repr(contents))
```

Comment: Using your code I get double backslashes for newlines and double quotes. I need the string to only contain single backslash escapes for all "escaped" characters. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LukeBergeron You should get the right stuff in `print(contents)` and double escaped stuff in `print(repr(contents))`. Does the first one look right?

Comment: Yes, the first one is perfect - I was only looking at the last printout. Thanks!